# How to set a local list/tuple variable in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way to do the following in mysql?

```
SET @studios = ('Disney', 'Warner Bros.', 'Fox');
SELECT * FROM movies WHERE provider IN @studios;
```

When I try doing the above I get the error:

> Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Comment: Is there a reason why you'd want to?

Comment: @Strawberry the above is a simplified query. I use the `@studios` variable about 5 times in the sql statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is coming from your initial assignment. You cannot assign lists to variables.

The only way of doing this in MySQL is to either create a temp table to hold the values, and then do `... IN (SELECT someVal FROM thatTemp)`, or to dynamically create the query with the values directly in the query string.

---

Example temp table creation:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `someTemp` ( someVal VARCHAR(16) );
INSERT INTO `someTemp` (someVal) VALUES ('a'), ('b'), ('c');
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myField IN (SELECT someVal FROM someTemp);
DELETE TEMPORARY TABLE `someTemp`;
```

---

Alternatively, there is also [FIND_IN_SET](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set), which could be used like this:

```
SET @list = 'a,b,c';
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE FIND_IN_SET(myField, @list) <> 0;
```

but this method probably has extremely poor performance (and may not be useable if your "myField" values may contain commas).

Comment: got it, thanks for the clarification. Could you please show how a tmptable would be created then in the above example?

Comment: Note that to remove the temporary table you need to use DROP not DELETE

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to set a tuple/list/array in a user-defined variable in MySQL. You can use [Dynamic SQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) for the same:

```
-- we use single quotes two times to escape it
SET @studios = '(''Disney'', ''Warner Bros.'', ''Fox'')';

-- generate the query string
SET @query = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM movies WHERE provider IN ', @studios);

-- prepare the query
PREPARE stmt FROM @query;

-- execute it
EXECUTE stmt;

-- deallocate it
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: great, this is a really useful example. Do you know since what version the above dynamic sql is available from? I'm using 5.6.

Comment: @David542 this is definitely available in version 5.5 and above. I think even version 4 and above has it as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could concatenate your list to a string, and use `FIND_IN_SET` as your criteria. Might not be super efficient, but makes the code quite easy to read and maintain.

Looks like this:

```
SET @studios = CONCAT_WS(',',
  'Disney',
  'Warner Bros.',
  'Fox'
);
SELECT * FROM movies 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(provider, @studios) <> 0;
```